# How to print a Bind10 cache dump?

Tags: cache, bind

How can you print the current state of the bind10 cache?

I searched the bind10 manual and tried to figure it out using `bindctl`.

Comment: Thank you for adding the bind10 keyword :). I coudn't do it, because the keyword did not exist and i have not enough reputation to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I search pretty extensively for this and did not find a method for doing this. I did go through the [User's Guide](http://bind10.isc.org/docs/bind10-guide.html), most of the [other docs](http://bind10.isc.org/docs/) as well as the [mailing lists](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind10-users/) and the [issue tracker](http://bind10.isc.org/wiki) for Bind 10 development.

I finally punted and asked a question about this particular issue on [ISC's knowledge base (KB)](https://kb.isc.org/). The ["Ask a Question"](http://www.isc.org/mission/contact/) feature doesn't give me a URL to reference, otherwise I would include that as well.

So for now I'm waiting to hear back from them via email. If that post anything I'll update my answer with anything that's relevant.